# Print object within object in vector c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm creating a project where I'm displaying a bank account. I've created a class Account and class Person - Account holds a balance, an account number, and an object of Person, which has a name and address. I've stored three Account objects in a vector, but can't figure out how to print the Person (namely, the name and address). Here are some snippets of my code inside my driver:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Account.h"
#include "Person.h"
using namespace std;

// Creates Person object Drew with name "Drew" address "60 N Main"
Person Drew("Drew", "60 N Main");
// Create Account DrewAccount with account number 1, using Person Drew,
// and setting balance to 500.00
Account DrewAccount(1, Drew, 500.00);

// This is inside my printAccount function
int size = accountVec.size();

for (unsigned int index = 0; index < size; index++)
{
    cout << accountVec[index].getAccountNum();

    // This accountHolder is the Person object Drew and is giving me issues
    // Gives Error:no operator "<<" matches these operands
    //          operand types are: std::ostream << Person
    cout << accountVec[index].getAccountHolder();

    cout << accountVec[index].getAccountBal();
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I suspect getAccountHolder() is the actual object being returned and you didn't override the <<operator. Can you show class definitions?

Comment: Add an overload operator `<<` to `Person` class, and use `cout << (Some person) << endl;`. See [operator overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators)

Comment: Also I don't see where the vector is populated?

Comment: Iterate over the vector and print the elements out like you would if they weren't in a vector. Oh wait! Does this have nothing to do with vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of doing it:

1)Assuming Person object has fields name and address attributes(std::string probably),
do this:

```
cout << accountVec[index].getAccountHolder().name;
cout << accountVec[index].getAccountHolder().address;
```

If the attributes are private, provide getname() and getaddress() operations to Person class and then, acess them.

```
cout << accountVec[index].getAccountHolder().getname();
cout << accountVec[index].getAccountHolder().getaddress();
```

2) If you have your own defined classes(types), define operator << for them.

```
 ostream &operator<<( ostream &output, const Person &D )
      { 
         output << "Person.xxxx";
         return output;            
      }
```

C++ is able to output the **built-in data types** using the stream insertion operator <<....But if you use custom defined types, ostream and your defined class(type) are the two types(operands) involved in insertion operator...hence the signature

```
ostream &operator<<( ostream &output, const Person &D )
```